# Switching from Eclipse indigo to Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-kepler

I have been using eclipse for about 2 years now and I had been using what ever the newest version was but about 6 moths ago I found out that I could use eclipse indigo and ever since I have been using it. I am wanting to switch to the new version of eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) and I'm wanting to know if i do switch will it mess up my work space from using indigo.

If i didn't explain some thing very well or missed spelled some thing please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your workspace itself will be OK you will have to re-do your presentation (perspective layouts...) since the 3.x and 4.x versions are imcompatible. You'll be reset to showing only the default perspective on your first start with 4.x (the 3.x description is not removed so it'll still be there if you go back).